# Failed to restart ntpd.service

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, ntp

I'm trying to fix error RequestTimeTooSkewed i get when trying to deploy a project to amazon servers i found this article.

http://www.emind.co/how-to/how-to-fix-amazon-s3-requesttimetooskewed/

I was following the steps but stucked at restarting the ntp service.

I used `service.ntpd restart`command but i get a error saying

```
Failed to restart ntpd.service: Unit ntpd.service not found.
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
$ systemctl start ntpd
```

If that doesn't work, probably ntp is not installed. Try installing it first.

```
$ sudo yum install ntp
```

Comment: $ systemctl start ntpd    gives me the same error and i have used yum previously. it too did not work

Comment: can you do `rpm -q ntp` please

Comment: I was able to use `sudo apt install -y ntp`. Thanks for the hint. +1

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me.

```
$ apt install ntpdate
$ apt install ntp
$ ntpdate -u "in.pool.ntp.org"
$ sudo service ntp restart
```

Note: Replace the server url "in.pool.net.org" with the ntp server available in your country.

Answer (score 1):

Keep Your Virtual OS machine running on Bridge Adapter and then try -

First run -> yum install ntp and the run

systemctl start ntpd

Answer (score 1):

These two commands fixed things for me in Ubuntu 20.04 server edition:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
sudo service ntp restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't resolve your problem with ntpd specifically, [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html#timesyncd) are some relevant docs on time-sync with npd on ubuntu that may be of help to some.

The key portion here is:

> In recent Ubuntu releases timesyncd replaces the client portion of ntpd. By default timesyncd regularly checks and keeps the time in sync. It also stores time updates locally, so that after reboots monotonically advances if applicable.
>
> The current status of time and time configuration via timedatectl and timesyncd can be checked with timedatectl status.

In summary: if `timedatectl status` shows `Network time on: yes`, then your system is already configured to use `ntp` in a similar way that would have been achieved with `ntpd`. This should be the default behavior for "recent" ubuntu releases (confirmed in 16.04).

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, the service name for ntpd is ntp, not ntpd.
So try

```
$ sudo service ntp restart
```

or, equivalently

```
$ sudo systemctl restart ntp
```